# Percona Server on cPanel - Missing mysql extension for PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cpanel, percona

I have replaced mysql with percona in a cpanel server, but I am having issue with wordpress and opencart sites which require php-mysql extension. This issue was not there before percona and I am able replicate the problem on another server where I repeated same, replacing usual mysql with percona.

Both times I followed this [cpanel documentation](http://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Replace+MySQL+with+Percona)

Please somebody help. All my wp and open cart sites are throwing errors.
"Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

SOLVED
I solved this issue. Basically the problem was with default libraries, php-mysql is no more default and it has been replaced with mysqlnd and official site has mentioned a way to compile php in this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php). I just referred this and recompiled the php and problem solved.

Thank you friends for trying to solve my problem and in fact due to your suggestions, I could solve this. Thanks  a lot, I dont know how to work on this site to thank you.

Comment: adding an engine to mysql shouldn't in any way affect the mysql drivers for php. that'd be like saying "putting fuzzy dice on my car's rearview mirror made my tires explode".

Comment: You are right in saying that, but this problem is there. I am following official cpanel documentation for this. When I uninstall percona and re-compile, it is giving no problem

Answer (score 0):

Percona MySQL is a in-place replacement for MySQL. For PHP applications, there is no difference. Check if "php5-mysql" is still installed. (e.g. using Ubuntu: apt-get install php5-mysql)

Comment: I have done this without any errors, but still problem.

Comment: Create a php file with the following content: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. This will display your current php configuration and will contain a part about mysql if installed. If it is missing, PHP mysql extension is not installed.

Comment: Strangely I noticed now, I didnt find mysql but instead found mysqlnd

Comment: mysqlnd is a drop-in replacement for the MySQL Client Library (libmysql). But you can use Percona MySQL with the default client library without any problems. Which OS are you using?

Comment: cPanel (Centos 6.5 64) with Litespeed, how to enable default percona mysql instead of this new one.

Comment: Never used CentOS, but this should install the "normal" mysql extension: `yum install php-mysql` Additionally you can remove mysqlnd using `yum erase php-mysqlnd`

Comment: I have edited my query with solution. tx for your help.